# Do all the 'balls' fit in the bowls?

Tags: design

Will [this ball](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54821pb03&name=Bionicle%20Zamor%20Sphere%20(Ball)%20with%20Marbled%20White%20Pattern&category=%5BBionicle%5D#T=C) fit in [this bowl?](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=122793&idColor=156#T=C&C=156)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only for a given value of "fit".

Both of these pieces are part of [set 70156-1, Legends of Chima "Fire vs. Ice"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70156-1#T=I).  On the front of the box, you can clearly see the blue ball 'sitting in' or resting on top of the white bowl, in front of the orange vehicle on the left.  It does not sit snugly inside.

[image: Picture of the Box for the Lego set. The ball rests on top of the bowl, but does not sit snugly within it]
[image: Image of the contents of the Set, also showing that the sphere does not sit within the bowl]

Answer (score 2):

No, both have a size of 2 studs.

Comment: 2 studs, not bricks.

Comment: @Alex right, thats what I meant, thanks